# MySQL 5.7 Docker version has lower transaction than the localhost version

Tags: docker-compose, transactions, mysql-5.7, sysbench

My VM is Ubuntu 18.04 and I install 2 instances of MySQL 5.7.

The first is installed in the localhost (port 3306), the second is installed via docker-compose (port 57306). The configurations cnf (which is from the default install of the localhost version) are all the same.

The Docker version only get **1700 Transactions** vs the localhost version with 4100 Transactions.

My question is, why the docker version is a lot slower, the configs are all the same, what could be the problems?

I test the localhost (port 3306) using sysbench with this command:

```
# prepare
sysbench --table_size=1000000 --db-driver=mysql --mysql-db=sysbench --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=<pass> /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_only.lua prepare

# run
sysbench --table_size=1000000 --db-driver=mysql --mysql-db=sysbench --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=<pass> --time=60 --max-requests=0 --threads=8 /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_only.lua run
```

and I got **4100 Transactions**

```
SQL statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            3444602
        write:                           0
        other:                           492086
        total:                           3936688
    transactions:                        246043 (4100.43 per sec.)
    queries:                             3936688 (65606.81 per sec.)
    ignored errors:                      0      (0.00 per sec.)
    reconnects:                          0      (0.00 per sec.)

General statistics:
    total time:                          60.0025s
    total number of events:              246043

Latency (ms):
         min:                                  0.88
         avg:                                  1.95
         max:                                 19.27
         95th percentile:                      3.13
         sum:                             479541.05

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           30755.3750/971.95
    execution time (avg/stddev):   59.9426/0.00
```

Next I deploy the docker version using this `docker-compose.yml` file in port 57306

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql57:
    build: ./bin/mysql57
    container_name: 'mysql-5.7'
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    ports:
      - "57306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./config/mysql57:/etc/mysql
      - ./data/mysql57:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs/mysql57:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <pass>
    entrypoint: ""
    command: bash -c "chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql && exec /entrypoint.sh mysqld"
```

The folder `./config/mysql57` is copied from the localhost configuration `(/etc/mysql)`

then I use this sysbench command

```
#prepare
sysbench --table_size=1000000 --db-driver=mysql --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 --mysql-port=57306 --mysql-db=sysbench --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=<pass> /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_only.lua prepare

#run
sysbench --table_size=1000000 --db-driver=mysql --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 --mysql-port=57306 --mysql-db=sysbench --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=<pass> --time=60 --max-requests=0 --threads=8 /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_only.lua run
```

I expect at least the transaction is near 4100 like above, but here it's only 1700

```
SQL statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            1431402
        write:                           0
        other:                           204486
        total:                           1635888
    transactions:                        102243 (1703.87 per sec.)
    queries:                             1635888 (27261.87 per sec.)
    ignored errors:                      0      (0.00 per sec.)
    reconnects:                          0      (0.00 per sec.)

General statistics:
    total time:                          60.0047s
    total number of events:              102243

Latency (ms):
         min:                                  3.01
         avg:                                  4.69
         max:                                 14.64
         95th percentile:                      5.99
         sum:                             479794.64

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           12780.3750/11.56
    execution time (avg/stddev):   59.9743/0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the low read tps for both your tests, it feels like cpu count is low. how many cores u got?? do you get stuck at 100% cpu when you run the test ?? if so this is unrealistic and unfair benchmark.

you are also running the client on the same machine it appears, which is taking even more CPU. why would dockerized version perform worse ?? port forwarding could be a cause. better yet you could be connecting over unix domain sockets on the host w/- knowing it.

In terms of CPU usage:
Unix domain > TCP > TCP over docker NAT

run the container with host networking, something like:

```sh
docker run --rm -it --network host -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bob123 mysql:5.7 --port 5306
```

"--network host" says the container sees the same network as the host. no software emulated virtual network involved.

remove the CPU bottleneck and run the tests again.